# Forcing redirect 301 from any domain urls to one only subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have an old domain

```
www.olddomain.com
```

and i want to redirect to

```
www.newdomain.com/slug1
```

BUT

if a user types

```
www.olddomain.com/folderX
```

she gets

```
www.newdomain.com/slug1folderX
```

instead of simply

```
newdomain.com/slug1
```

which is wrong of course

how can i fix my apache? is it doable in the .conf files or htaccess?

**UPDATE**

this is my current virtual host .conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName olddomain.it
    ServerAlias www.olddomain.it
    Redirect 301 / https://www.newdomain.it/slug
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

On old domain's site root .htaccess you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com/slug1? [L,R=302]
```

Remember to clear your browser cache before testing this rule.

Comment: btw i added in my ask, the current conf. should i remove it and keep the rule just in the htaccess?

Comment: Comment out `Redirect` line and place these lines from my answer and then restart Apache